# How do I debug performance drops within my site?

Tags: performance, debugging, firefox, web-applications, firefox-developer-tools

I'm experiencing quite a bit of performance lag within my site on initial load and would like to debug this area. How can I utilize tools such as Firefox dev tools Performance tab to track down the exact reasons my site is lagging?

How can I utilize these tools (or what's the best practice) to understand what within my code is causing this to happen?

[Here's an image of my Performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjcGS.jpg)

Comment: Firefox can only debug client site code (JavaScript and some web assembly). So if the problem is on the server side (slow queries, bad caching, bad design patterns) then Firefox can't help you.

Comment: There's some [description of the *Performance* tab including an explanatory video on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance).